# Hyperlink in ::after in HTML

Tags: html, css

How can i make a hyperlink of a ::after section in HTML, for example:

```
<span>This is an example</span>

span:after
{
     content: "...read more";
}
```

output will be:

> This is an example...read more.

I want ...read more to be hyperlink. Is that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704802/css-after-element-to-insert-mailto-link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it’s not possible. Generated content can only take the form of either static text or static image content, and not entire DOM elements.

Nor is this the kind of thing `::after` is meant to be used for. There is no reason not to mark up a hyperlink within your document, since you're expressing a link between this document and some other document.