# How to get hyperlinks inside a "pop-up" term reference on mouse-over, and seperate the HTML term from the "pop-up" reference content

Tags: jquery, html, css

This article is a follow-up/reformulation of the less-specific formulated question [Is it possible to have a hyperlink inside {content:"..."}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087772/is-it-possible-to-have-a-hyperlink-inside-content/28087923#28087923).

---

User [Naeem Shaikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3556874/naeem-shaikh), to whom many thanks, friendly and successfully helped me having a hyperlink on mouse-hover, after an HTML tag with a specific id (here called `"HPV"`), using jQuery. Full credit for the JS help goes to him.

When I adapted this to my specific content (a term description), I get the following (formerly: JSFiddle 1):

## HTML

```
<br><br>
<a class="term" id="HPV">HPV</a>
```

## CSS

```
a.term{text-decoration:underline; text-decoration-style:dotted; -moz-text-decoration-style:dotted}

a.term:hover{text-decoration:none; color:#aaaaaa}

a.term:hover:after{position:relative; padding: 1px; top:-0.9em; left:-5px; border:1px dotted #aaaaaa; color:black; background-color:white}

a.term#HPV:hover:after{content:"Human papillomavirus."}
```

## JS (requires jQuery)

```
$(function(){
    $('#HPV').hover(function(e){
       $(this).append('<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus"> Wikipedia.</a>');
    },function(){
       $(this).find('a').remove();
    });
});
```

Now my next question is how to get the hyperlink **"inside/after"** the content of the after-selector. Instead of just after the content of the original HTML tag itself.

In my example: after "Human papillomavirus.", as such:

---

*Human papillomavirus. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus).*
HPV

---

Instead of how it is now:

---

*Human papillomavirus.*
HPV *[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus).*

---

I guess this calls for an ingenious way to have these links positioned inside the `content` of the `:after-selector`: especially when more than 1 link should be inserted, with extra text/content in between.

### ---

A small remark/glitch: as it is now, you can't put the "*dot*" `.`after [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus) on the right-side of the `</a>` in the JS. Or rather: you can, but then the CSS of the original tag (in CSS: `a.term:hover`) would unfortunately be adopted (cf. the gray color of the `.` then).

The same behavior can be seen now, since, the hyperlink adopts the gray color of the "parent" tag.

### ---

Another way to generally deal with the whole question (to have hyperlinks inside such a "on-hover term description"), is not to use the CSS `:after`-selector, and manually have an extra e.g. `div`, right after the original HTML tag, to account for a "pop-up description", as such (formerly: JSFiddle 2):

## HTML

```
<br>

<a id="term">HPV</a><div>Human papillomavirus. <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus">Wikipedia</a>.</div>
```

## CSS

```
a#term:hover + div{display:inline} a#term + div{display:none; border:1px dotted #aaaaaa; padding:1px; top:-1em; position:relative}
```

Of course this is not ideal, because this is a trade-off with loss of ease on data-handling (especially when a term occurs multiple times in a document) and HTML readability.

Without the `:after`-tag also, could be to have a more jQuery centered approach, and to have the full content (regular text and links) of the reference inside the jQuery. One could then use some additional CSS on the jQuery, I suppose?

Comment: (typo) You have extra notations `;;`

Comment: Is `<term>` a valid HTML5 tag?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I see, thanks. At these 2 instances, should I just I keep 1 `;` or remove both `;;`? It is still working when I remove both, but would that be the "normal/safe/readable" way? -- I am very unexperienced with JS.

Comment: No, `<term>` isn't a standard HTML-any? tag. Is it a beginner's mistake to choose non-standard tags? I find it better readable and time saving.

Comment: Browsers like IE won't recognize non-standard tags. For conveying meaning, use classes. Eg: `<div class="term">...whatever...</div>` and use class selectors: `.term:hover {etc: et al;}`

Comment: While modern browsers usually won't make a fuss of unknown tags, you might get unknown behavior on some devices. Also, you're defeating the point of semantics entirely, for example, your site would be practically unusable to anyone using reading aid or anything likewise.

Comment: Thank you @Kroltan. I'll stick with `<a id="...">` then, I think, in this case, as it is shorter than `class`, if that wouldn't cause too much problems? --- And thank you @Nit, that's interesting, I wasn't aware of that problem. One reason more to standardize. --- I'll do that in a moment.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - How about this? ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6khspLg1/3/)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py - I'll adjust my title to make my reply more relevant. You answered perfectly, my title was not to the point, I'm sorry. --- Very nice, but you have the same problem as with the alternative way ([JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/VincentVerheyen/pkg8h762/1/)), described in the question. I agree that this is workable, but I think it might be good to seperate the content of the pop-up "positionally" (in the code) from the original HTML term. --- I even think it might be better, actually, to provide a solution completely without the `:after`-selector, and use only the JS-solution.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen It's actually considered better practice to use CSS for presentational effects, rather than JavaScript or a JS library like jQuery, where you can. Is there a specific reason you want to keep the content out of the HTML? Any size added to the file from additional markup is saved with more efficient CSS and no JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: @TylerH.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087772/is-it-possible-to-have-a-hyperlink-inside-an-aftercontent-selector-onl/28087923#28087772 previous question by OP

Comment: @TylerH - The reason was mainly the same as the reason why [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is successful: so that you can read the HTML in an intuitive content-focused way, without being distracted by the meta-markup. --- Further more, it would be easy (read: in a single position) to adapt the "pop-up" reference of a certain term, when this term is occurring frequently throughout the document.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen I'm not sure I follow. The audience is normal people, or web developers analyzing your markup? If it's the former, then CSS will hide meta-information until mouse-over, no problem there. If it's the latter, then no, developers looking through markup are not concerned with how it reads to them *within the markup*. Either way your concern is not really a problem. It is just as hidden in the final output whether you use JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: @TylerH - Interesting analysis. You are right of course about both the interests of both these target audiences. --- However, my target audience (as for the coding behind the scenes) is that of the writer himself, which is in this case both a coder as also a writer of content. In this sense, I referred to the ease of the WYSIWYG-trademark of Markdown. --- As I am working with Drupal, another way to achieve this would be the [taxonomy tooltip](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_tooltip)-module, but unfortunately I wasn't able to get that to work.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen, responding your response about IDs: If you prefer... Just remember that IDs ***must*** be unique on the page, no two elements can ever share the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sup`  to show content on hover, as suggested by chipChocolate.py. but as from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087772/is-it-possible-to-have-a-hyperlink-inside-an-aftercontent-selector-onl/28087923#28087772) previous question by  OP and my [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/1ysyr0tb/2/) , I think you could just use a combination of both solutions.

The content is dynamically added to the dom via jquery, and using the markup chipChocolate.py suggested in comment above. see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/u1vexjds/2/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#HPV').hover(function(e){
       $(this).append('<sup>Human papillomavirus<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus"> Wikipedia.</a></sup>');
    },function(){
       $(this).find('sup').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, at all the people who discussed this, thought together and all made enriching remarks. Thank you @Naeem Shaikh especially for the continued effort. --- Do you know perhaps how to add additional lay-out to the `.append(...)`? Since now it automatically adapts the color of the term (in this case: gray, since hovered). --- My current solution is inside the jQuery: change `<sup>` to `<sup style="color:black">`, but I think a CSS solution would be easier and more centralized, allowing easy overall document-wise changes. --- Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Clarification by OP.

Here's just a full code clarification of [Naeem Shaikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3556874/naeem-shaikh)'s answer, implemented as a fully integrated answer to the original question.

Please, vote for him, if you like his answer. This is just a clarification.

Because of [Kroltan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045510/kroltan)'s  comment I now switched the particular use of `id` and `term`, to fully allow multiple occurrences of the same term.

## HTML

```
<br><a id="term" class="HPV">HPV</a>
<br><a id="term" class="HPV">HPV</a>
<br><a id="term" class="QA">QA</a>
```

## CSS

```
a#term{text-decoration:underline; text-decoration-style:dotted; -moz-text-decoration-style:dotted} a.term:hover{text-decoration:none; color:#aaaaaa}
a#term:hover{text-decoration:none; color:#aaaaaa}
```

## JS (requires jQuery)

```
$(function(){$('.HPV').hover(function(e){$(this).append('<sup style="color:black"> Human papillomavirus. See: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus">Wikipedia</a>.</sup>');},function(){$(this).find('sup').remove();});});
$(function(){$('.QA').hover(function(e){$(this).append('<sup style="color:black">Quality assurance. See: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_assurance"> Wikipedia</a>.</sup>');},function(){$(this).find('sup').remove();});});
```

---

If anyone would know how to change the color (or other CSS elements) of the content of jQuery's `.append(...)` ***inside CSS*** itself, thus "seperated" from the jQuery code? This would also be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like multiple things have the same id, isn't that a huge no no? just give it two classes, one term, one HPV or QA