# replace text to link through css only

Tags: css

it must be very simple question but im struggling to find a solution.
I would like to change the title text to my own text as a link through css.
this is what i have so far:

```
.title {
   display: none;
}

.title::before {
  content: "here is my text as a link ???..."
}
```

the text displays ok, but do not understand how to make it work as a link?!any ideas?!
the question is - what to add to my style (::before) to make text look and actually work as a link to other page of my app ?!
Thank you!

Comment: `a` elements have some special behavior that you can't achieve in pseudo-elements.

Comment: Pseudo elements cannot contain HTML..nor should they contain **actual content** they are for **styling** not content.

Comment: ok, thanks. didn't know about it. the css is still darkside for me lol

Comment: What keeps you from using an actual `<a>` tag, no CSS involved?

Comment: you need to make link with css

Comment: you will find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9704986/3836908

Comment: possible duplicate ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704802/css-after-element-to-insert-mailto-link

Comment: I have no access to HTML code, only CSS ...

Answer (score 0):

Give your Url in that and check it out:

```
.title::after {
 content: "here is my text as a link ???...",url(http://www.w3schools.com/);
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, I've tried this earlier ... looks like Oriol and Paulie_D are wright, we cannot use HTML tags with pseudo elements .. Thanks anyway!