# Turn text to link by css

Tags: css

Is it possible to convert a text to  link by its id in CSS.

```
<span id="text">A text</span>
```

Change above text by CSS to a link like this:

```
<span id="text"><a href="example.org">A text</a></span>
```

Comment: where is the href information ie "example.org" stored ?? before the transform

Comment: No, it is not possible. You cannot create HTML with CSS.

Comment: why would you want that

Comment: It is possible to make it look like a link (underline, pointer cursor), but it is not possible to make it work like a link. After all, in your example, how would the span know *where* to link?

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Do you really need to make a hyperlink with CSS? Or do you actually want to know how to place a hyperlink _in JavaScript_ (because that’s the only interactive language that supports such a thing)?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704802/css-after-element-to-insert-mailto-link)

Comment: WordPress widgets do not support links for their header titles. They accept pure text only. That's why I need to turn it to a link by css. So how can I do this without CSS. Is there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible to do via CSS**

Links are considered content, which is separate from presentation (CSS). This is by design. Content like this can only be added to the page by modifying the DOM - either dynamically in the browser via JavaScript and/or by changing the HTML returned from server-side code.

To do specifically what you are asking for, you could use JavaScript like this...

```js
const el = document.getElementById('text')
el.innerHTML = `<a href="example.org">${el.textContent}</a>`
```

```html
<span id="text">A text</span>
```

...but this is often better:

```js
const parentElement = document.getElementById('text')
const newElement = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
  href: 'example.org',
  textContent: parentElement.textContent
})
parentElement.textContent = ''
parentElement.appendChild(newElement)
```

```html
<span id="text">A text</span>
```

It may look more complicated than `el.innerHTML='...'`, but this way doesn't need to be parsed, so it is the faster approach.

Comment: Ok. So how can I add a link to end of that by ":after" in CSS. When I add link with ":before" or ":after", it turns to rich text and html tags are not rendered.

Comment: As you saw, you cannot do that. `content` doesn't turn into HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to manipulate HTML you can do by JavaScript but there's no way to do this with css.
Example

```
document.getElementById('your id').innerHTML = '<a href=""></a>';
```

You can find more  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)